# Why would "unused import" be a fatal compilation error with sbt?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Is there any place i should look for to locally make these warns at compile time, not errors?

Comment: It is a warning, you probably have the `-Xfatal-warnings` flag on your **SBT** build, which makes the warning an error.

Comment: This is not an error by default, you must have this enabled via a compiler flag. Check your Scala options in `build.sbt`. However, you could also just fix by removing the import.

Answer (score 4):

This is needed to keep your import section as small and clean as possible. Moreover, wildcard imports in certain circumstances could cause implicit clash on an additional implicit declaration. That's why.

How to disable - "-Xfatal-warnings" should be searched for in sbt files and removed. Also, you could search for "-Ywarn-unused-import" to disable this warning.

Comment: featured not yet in  `Scala 3` unfortunately